# Eliminate limits for port connection for Redis on CentOS

Tags: linux, networking, ulimit

I am using Redis caching server on CentOS, where Redis accepts clients connections on the configured listening TCP port. I am trying to figure out the limits applied by the operating system to the number of connection allowed to the single configured port for redis.

The user being used is `root` as shown:

```
[root@server-001]# ps -ef | grep -i redis 
root     19595     1  9 Jun26 ?        09:43:07 /usr/local/bin/redis-server 0.0.0.0:6379
```

Now I am tricked by multiple factors:

1. The value of file-max is:

   ```
   [root@server-001]# cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
   6518496
   ```
2. The value of `limits.conf`:

   ```
   [root@server-001]# cat /etc/security/limits.d/20-nproc.conf 
   # Default limit for number of user's processes to prevent
   # accidental fork bombs.
   # See rhbz #432903 for reasoning.

   *          soft    nproc     4096
   root       soft    nproc     unlimited
   ```
3. The soft and hard limit of file descriptors:

   ```
   [root@server-001]# ulimit -Hn
   4096
   [root@server-001]# ulimit -Sn
   1024
   ```

Now, knowing that the the real factor limits connection to a single port is file descriptors, which one I have to change to make sure that the redis server is accepting as much clients as it is possible?

Comment: Why are you attempting to fine tune something like this and in this way? Unless you have a true need to do something like this you shouldn’t.

Comment: I do, I am getting errors from Redis that maximum number of client is reached, the number on Redis config is pretty high, 100K, so am sure the number is limited somewhere else.

Comment: what makes you think client limits are related os port configuration defaults?

Comment: @FrankThomas As I mentioned in the question, Redis accepts clients connections on the configured listening TCP port, and Redis configuration allow 100K client connection, So it should be limited by the OS.